# When nesting divs within a div on an HTML page, background color positioning looks off

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to create an effect where I have a tall bordered div, with 3 equally sized divs inside of it, each inner div with its own background color.

I thought the css "math" would be easy for this, but my results look wrong.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #main {
        height: 156px;
        width: 52px;
        background: #CECECE;
        border: 4px solid gray;
        border-radius: 4px;  
      }

      .inner {
        width: 52px;
        height: 52px;
      }

      #i1 {
        background: green;
      }

      #i2 {
        background: red;
      }

      #i3 {
        background: blue;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id='main'>
      <div id='i1' class='inner'></div>
      <div id='i2' class='inner'></div>
      <div id='i3' class='inner'></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[JS Fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/wdxq2x6w)

Does anyone know why part of my main div's background is showing through inside of its border and how I can fix it?

In case the way your browser renders the fiddle is different than mine (I'm using Chrome), here is what I see (my problem is the light gray showing through from the main div background on the inside top, left and right of my border):

[My browser's rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQrQ4.png)

Comment: displays properly in my broswer (chrome) no inner border like in your image

Comment: Makes me think something might be wrong with my Chrome installation. Only thing I can think of is to try reinstalling it.

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify the CSS: Erase the `height` setting from  `#main` and the `width` setting from `.inner`. That way the inner DIVs will fill the whole width of `#main`, and `#main` will get its height from its content - the three inner DIVs.

```css
      #main {
        width: 52px;
        background: #CECECE;
        border: 4px solid gray;
        border-radius: 4px;  
      }

      .inner {
        height: 52px;
      }

      #i1 {
        background: green;
      }

      #i2 {
        background: red;
      }

      #i3 {
        background: blue;
      }
```

```html
  <body>
    <div id='main'>
      <div id='i1' class='inner'></div>
      <div id='i2' class='inner'></div>
      <div id='i3' class='inner'></div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Yes off course! :) stupid me should have noticed that as a potential cause.. +1

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your zoom level isn't on 100%. Left is a screenshot of your image, middle is how my Chrome renders it on 100%, right is my Chrome on 80%. I can't seem to reproduce your exact zoom level, but as you can see, similar issues show up at different zoom levels...

[image: Rendered on different zoom levels]

Comment: Checked and it was on 100%. At various zoom levels both above and below 100, the background either looks correct or I get a "different" problem somewhat like the rightmost image you include. Again making me think something is corrupted with my install of Chrome.

Comment: Well, that was my best guess, you can check if any odd chrome://flags/ are throwing a spanner in the works before reinstalling...